# How to increase concision and performance in a function to retrieve sentences where keywords match?

Tags: php, strings, search

I'm building a text search system for a web application in PHP. I wrote this function that gets the sentences of the text which contains the keywords used by the user and also highlight them (well, surround them with any tags anyway).

I'm measuring an average of 23ms if only the first matches is retrieved, and about 27ms if I choose to get all of the matches. It doesn't seem much, but I'll use it for all search results in a page and many users might be doing a search at the same time.

The function is somewhat long but I heavily commented it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Return the highlighted excerpts, given the text and the keywords. This can show
 * ALL phrases with keywords or just the first matches (in both cases, no phrase is
 * repeated, even containing more than one keyword, but all keywords are highlighted.
 * 
 * @param string $text The text in which to perform the search.
 * @param array $keywords A list of keywords to search.
 * @param string $prefix The prefix for the highlighting (i.e. the opening tag).
 * @param string $suffix The suffix for the highlighting (i.e. the closing tag).
 * @param boolean $only_first Whether to show only the first match or all of them.
 * @return string A text with the matched keywords an the surrounding phrases, separated
 *                by ellipsis (...).
 */
function excerpts($text, $keywords, $prefix = '<b>', $suffix = '</b>', $only_first = TRUE)
{
    // Replacing null prefix suffix for default values.
    if ($prefix === NULL)
    {
        $prefix = '<b>';
    }
    if ($suffix === NULL)
    {
        $suffix = '</b>';
    }
    // Split the text in an array
    $text_array = preg_split("/([^\w]+)/u", $text, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $text_array_len = count($text_array);
    // Use a lower case version for case insensitive search
    // And remove accents to also ignore them.
    $map = function($el){
        return strtolower(iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $el));
    };
    $lowers = array_map($map, $text_array);
    // Have to do the same with the keywords
    $keywords = array_map($map, $keywords);

    $matches = array();
    // Get the keys where the values matches the keywords
    if ($only_first)
    {
        foreach ($keywords as $word)
        {
            $matches[] = array_search($word, $lowers);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($keywords as $word)
        {
            $matches = array_merge($matches, array_keys($lowers, $word));
        }
    }

    // The result must be in the same order as the original text
    sort($matches);

    $result = array();
    // Keep track of previous phrases, to check if the current phrase
    // is the same as the previous and avoid repeating.
    $previous_start = $text_array_len;
    $previous_end = 0;
    foreach ($matches as $key)
    {
        // Find the nearest period before this matched key
        $first_period = -1;
        for ($j = $key - 1; $j >= 0; $j--)
        {
            if (preg_match('/\./', $text_array[$j]))
            {
                $first_period = $j;
                break;
            }
        } unset($j);

        // Check if we already did this phrase:
        if (($first_period + 1) >= $previous_start && ($first_period + 1) <= $previous_end)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Now we set the previous values
        $previous_start = $first_period + 1;
        $previous_end = $text_array_len - 1;

        // Put an ellipsis only if not at the beginning
        if ($previous_start != 0)
        {
            $result[] = ' ... ';
        }

        // Go from there forward to the next period
        for ($j = $previous_start; $j < $text_array_len; $j++)
        {
            // If it's a period and we already showed the key, stop it
            if ($j > $key && (strpos($text_array[$j], '.') !== FALSE))
            {
                $previous_end = $j;
                break;
            }
            // If it's one keyword, surround it
            if (in_array($j, $matches))
            {
                $result[] = $prefix . $text_array[$j] . $suffix;
            }
            else
            {
                $result[] = $text_array[$j];
            }
        }
    }
    // This is tricky: it puts the last period of the text
    // if we stopped just a bit before
    if ($previous_end == ($text_array_len - 2))
    {
        $result[] = $text_array[$text_array_len - 1];
    }
    // If we didn't reach the finish, show the ellipsis
    elseif ($previous_end < ($text_array_len - 2))
    {
        $result[]= ' ...';
    }
    // Bring the array together again to a string
    return implode('', $result);
}
```

Is there a way to increase performance? Am I overreacting? Can it be more concise and/or more simple?

Comment: Why complicate the wrapping so much? Can't you just use something like this? https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/6738783

Comment: @elclanrs I use both prefix and suffix because the tag may contain attributes (such as style or class), hence they might be different. But doing the overall wrapping later may be neater. Thanks for the tip.